# type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am getting error type '_file' is not the sub type of 'string' in type cast. I am trying to upload video to rest api. here is my video api

```
 Future createVideo(String user_id , File file) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('api'),
      /* headers: {
      'Accept': 'multipart/form-data'
    },*/
      body: {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'file': _video != null ? 'data:video/mp4;base64,' +
            base64Encode(_video!.readAsBytesSync()) : '',
      },
    );

    final responseJson = await json.decode(json.encode(response.body));

    print(responseJson);
  }
```

here is how i am uploading video from camera

```
 Future _pickVideoFromCamera() async {
    final  pickVideo = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_video!)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _video = File(pickVideo!.path);
        });
        videoPlayerController!.play();
      });

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      var myId = prefs.getString('user_id');

      print(myId);
      var myProfile = _video;
      print(myProfile);
    createVideo(

        myId!,
        myProfile!,
      );
  }
```

and here i am showing i am replacing video on image when its upload

```
_video == null
                  ?
                  Container(
                    width: 326.w,
                    height: 190.h,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image:
    AssetImage('assets/images/video/videouser.png')
                        )
                    ),
                  ):  Container(
                width: 326.w,
                height: 190.h,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(
                    videoPlayerController!,
                  ),
                ),

              ) ,
```

the video is showing and playing successfully but i am getting error when i upload to rest api

```
E/flutter (28110): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter (28110): #0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25)
E/flutter (28110): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:400:8)
E/flutter (28110): #2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13)
E/flutter (28110): #3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7)
E/flutter (28110): #4      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:137:12)
E/flutter (28110): #5      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:87:17)
E/flutter (28110): #6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter (28110): #7      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:69:16)
E/flutter (28110): #8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:20)
E/flutter (28110): #9      post (package:http/http.dart:68:5)
E/flutter (28110): #10     videoUser (package:appsolut_soccer/services/video_api.dart:8:26)
E/flutter (28110): #11     _UploadVideoState._pickVideoFromCamera (package:appsolut_soccer/src/Video_Screen/upload_video.dart:109:5)
E/flutter (28110): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28110):
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the `print(myProfile);` statement it should take a `String` and you are passing a `File`

Comment: what is the videouser here? I mean this:
 `videoUser(myId!, myProfile!, )`

Comment: i check it bro getting same error

Comment: @BosS i update the question basically videoUser is api name where i define my id and profile

Comment: i also get error null operator check on null value